# How to use a date variable in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have cell A1 in excel with the value `3/09/2018`. I can convert it to a date in VBA as follows.

`startdate = Format(#3/09/2018#, "Short Date")`

However I cant get this to work with a variable, for example:

```
value1=  ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value
final_value = "#" & value1 & "#"
startdate= Format(final_value,"Short Date")
```

How can I get this working with the `final_value` variable? I am trying to get the result working with a filter in this way:

`ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter =1, Criteria1=">="startdate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bother with the var being a date-type? All you need to do anything in VBA is 43168 (or 43346 if you use DMY and thought VBA was DMY-friendly).

```
dim startDate as long
startDate = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value2
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming startdate is declared as a Date variable, you could just use:

```
startdate = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value
```

Now that you've clarified what you're doing, I'd use a `Double` for an autofilter (especially if there might be international issues) or a Long if you aren't interested in time portions:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1=">=" & ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value2
```

or:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1=">=" & CLng(ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value2)
```

Comment: Declaring the start date as a variable and doing this way still doesn't work. I'm trying to use this with a filter and have edited my question. Thanks